# How to add all result from a Jooq query to a Map

Tags: java, jooq

I want to add all results from a jooq query (MySQL) like this:

```
organizationDSLContext.select(
                       Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE.ID_ORGANIZATION,
                       DSL.jsonArrayAgg(Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE.ID_ROLE))
                      .from(Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE)
                .where(Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE.ID_USER.eq(UserService.DEFAULT_ID_USER))
                .groupBy(Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE.ID_ORGANIZATION)
                .fetchGroups(Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE.ID_ORGANIZATION, DSL.jsonArrayAgg(Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE.ID_ROLE));
```

Into a map like Map<Integer, List<'Integer>> mapList;

How can I modify the query so that I can save the data in that map?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED**

This is the correct query for my problem :)

```
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> mapList = organizationDSLContext.selectFrom(Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE)
            .where(Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE.ID_USER.eq(UserService.DEFAULT_ID_USER))
            .fetchGroups(Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE.ID_ORGANIZATION, Tables.USER_ORGANIZATION_ROLE.ID_ROLE);
```